# Laravel - Mixed Content just on post request

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-6

**Message error:**

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example/contracts/create' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://example:443/api/v1/contracts'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

I saw some similar posts, but till now it didn't work.(my .env is with https, and this is not local)
I got this error just on this post, the rest of them are with https, and only when I have error validation.
On local it's working fine.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->prefix('contracts')->group(function () {
    Route::get('{contract?}', 'ContractsController@getContracts');} //in api.php

post("/contracts/" + `${this.customer_id}`, newContract) // in VueJs
```

Comment: What is making the request to `http://example:443/api/v1/contracts`? What does that code look like?

Comment: I edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to `app\Provider\AppServiceProvider`

```
/**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if (!app()->isLocal()) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using this on boot function, there.    if (!app()->isLocal()) {         URL::forceScheme('https');}

Comment: maybe in someplace you hard code with http, could you check again?

Comment: How did you pass the route from laravel down to javascript?

Comment: From api.php, and after that from my router.js file ,in VueJs. (This error is just on post request when I have validation errors (so catch)). But I use the same post for other pages an there I have when I get validation Errors.